# Convert DataResponse<Data> to expected type DataResponse<Any>?

Tags: swift, types, alamofire

I have a protocol for handling my requests like this:

```
protocol NetworkResponseProcessor {
  var completionBlock : NetworkRequestCompletionBlock {get set}

  init(completionBlock : @escaping NetworkRequestCompletionBlock)

  func processResponse(response : DataResponse<Any>?)
  func processError(error : Error?)
}
```

In one of my upload requests using Alamofire I want to pass the response to the `processResponse` method. However, the response is of type `DataResponse<Data>` and now Xcode tells me it cannot convert this type to the expected argument type `DataReponse<Any>?`.

My call looks like this:

```
Network.shared.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(fileURL, withName: "content")
        },
    usingThreshold: UInt64.init(),
    to: endpoint,
    method: method,
    headers: headers) { (encodingResult) in
      switch encodingResult {
      case .success(let upload, _, _):
          upload.validate().responseData(completionHandler: { (response) in
              self.responseProcessor.processResponse(response: response)
          })
      case .failure(let encodingError):
          print(encodingError)
          self.responseProcessor.processError(error: NetworkRequestError.InvalidJSONData)
      }
}
```

In this code `Network` is a singleton using `shared` as `SessionManager`.

If I use `responseJSON`, instead of `responseData`, Xcode is happy, but since the response is binary data, I can't use that method for obvious reasons.
How should I solve the error Xcode is giving me?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I would say you do something like this: `processResponse(response : DataResponse<T>?)` but that doesn't compile. I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: Not yet; I'll look into it shortly.